# Call Controllers Action method from Button in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to call one of two action methods in my controller `Client` using a button. This is for a simple CRUD style web application however neither of the action methods are invoked at all (I have breakpoints set). My HTML code is as follows:

```
@if (Model == null || Model.ID == 0)
{
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href = ''@Url.Action("AddClient", "Client")''"/>Add New Details</span>
}
else
{
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href = ''@Url.Action("UpdateClient", "Client")''"/>Update Client Details</span>
}
```

I do not want the page to reload and would rather accomplish this without using jQuery (if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you don't want to reload the page, but presumably you want the page to update in some way after the call to the server.

Instead of a button I generally use a link that is styled like a button:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add New Details", "AddClient", "Client",
    new { /*action params*/ },
    new AjaxOptions()
        {
            Confirm = "Are you sure you want to add new details?",
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnComplete = "afterAddition()"
        },
    new { @class = "btn btn-default" }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra single quotes at the place where you specify location.href, remove those as shown below and it should hit you action methods,

```
@if (Model == null || Model.ID == 0)
{
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("AddClient", "Client")'"/>Add New Details</span>
}
else
{
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("UpdateClient", "Client")'"/>Update Client Details</span>
}
```

You can use MVC Ajax options in case you want partial loads.